# Using Google APIs from automated task with OAuth

Tags: ruby, google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I have a regular, automated task that needs to query user data within the Google Analytics API. It must be able to run without manual intervention.

(Details, details: I'm presently using the Ruby gems `legato` and `oauth` to do the queries.)

As best as I can tell, because I want to query user data on Google Analytics, I *must* use OAuth 2.0. Yet the access token that I acquire expires after 1 hour, and the refresh token only appears to work in the presence of a valid access token(?).

I've obtained a long-living OAuth 1.0a token for a twitter bot script that runs as a daily cron job. It's been running daily for several years with nary a problem.

It *appears* that for Google/OAuth 2.0, I have to acquire a token manually, have the task refresh its token occasionally, and re-acquire a token manually if the job were ever to die. I have a hard time believing that this is actually the case. What am I missing?

Comment: Yeah you are missing something.  You are correct that the access token only lasts for 1 hour.  But you should be able to refresh it at ANY time using the refresh token (without manual intervention).  You must be doing something wrong.  Check the documentation again.  I have created Windows based services which query GA data and it is fully automated.  You should be using the **http://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token** call.

Comment: I was probably using the refresh token incorrectly--the documentation is abysmal--but the service account I mention below has done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, hello, it's called a [Service Account](https://github.com/tpitale/legato/wiki/OAuth2-and-Google#service-accounts). An initial, cursory reading of Google's docs had me thinking that service accounts could not access user data, but it turns out this is the correct way to do it.